# Is there a way to delete trimmed parts of a video on iOS?

Tags: iphone, photos, ios

So I have recorded some pretty long videos with the intention of trimming them once recorded. However I totally forgot to consider storage space. And when I trim a video I realise that I am able to stretch it back to full length, meaning that the video full video is being stored on my device!

Is there a way to delete the parts I don’t want and keep only the trimmed parts to save storage space?

I am running the latest version of iOS as of the time of posting: iOS 13.2